# tvOS UIButton .plain style without blurred background view

Tags: uibutton, tvos

UIButtonType.plain is "A standard system button without a blurred background view." in tvOS 11. However, when I try to make a `.plain` UIButton and change its background color to red, I can still see a VisualEffectView in the UIButton which darkens the red color. How can I get rid of the blurred background view and get a real plain button with motion effect? Thanks.

[snapshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/iepeH.png)

Answer (score 0):

Customizations for `UIButton` on tvOS is limited and you may not be able to get the desired effect without subclassing `UIButton`.

However, one workaround without subclassing is to use images and set the background image for your button.

There are several open source libraries that may fit your requirements. The one I've been using for my project with great success is:
[FocusTvButton](https://github.com/dcordero/FocusTvButton)

Answer (score 0):

I use this workaround in my project:

`button.titleLabel?.superview?.backgroundColor = .red`

With this method you won't be able to set different color for states. If you doesn't care about different background color for focused state, this can help you.
Otherwise I think you should subclass `UIButton` and set appropriate colors in `didUpdateFocus` and `pressesBegan`